# Spock inmemory implementation mapstruct autowired inside mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spock, mapstruct

Hi I want to test some method using in memory implementation without h2.

[image]

In impl of userMapper I have.

[image]

When I try to run my test, I have NullPointerException of this passwordEncoderMapper.
How can I inject to filed autowire like on first screenshoot(authService) **without** load spring context (**@SpringBootTest**).

Comment: Please edit your question, replacing the screenshots by code blocks. Looking at some of your previous questions, you know how to do that already. Ideally, present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not just incoherent sets of snippets which nobody can compile and run in order to reproduce your problem. That would significantly increase your chances to get spot-on answers. Thank you. The question is also somewhat unclear - at least I do not understand it - and you also forgot to post a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have a `NullPointerException` for the `passwordEncoderMapper` is because you are mixing the spring `componentModel` with `Mappers#getMapper`. You shouldn't do that.

When you are using a custom `componentModel` you should always use that dependency injection in order to get the mappers.

What you can do for tests is to use `Mapper#injectionStrategy` with `InjectionStrategy#CONSTRUCTOR` and then instantiate the mapper on your own by providing the correct dependencies to it.

Comment: Thanks, is works