# How to test mapstruct mapper with nested mappers using Groovy + Spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock, mapstruct

I'd like to test mapstruct mapper with nested mappers using Groovy + Spock without any Spring Boot context. How to do that?

My Mapper:

```
@Mapper(uses = {
                PathToPathDto.class,
                businessToSmallBusinessDto.class,
                StoreToStoreDto.class
        }, componentModel = "spring")
public interface WindowDtoMapper {

    WindowDtoMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(WindowDtoMapper.class);

    WindowInDetailsDto mapToWindowInDetailsDto(Window window);

    WindowReadDto mapToWindowReadDto(Window window);
}
```

And all my nested mappers in "using" section are similar:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PathToPathDto {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spock inmemory implementation mapstruct autowired inside mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229314/spock-inmemory-implementation-mapstruct-autowired-inside-mapper)

Comment: Probably yes! But how to set InjectionStrategy#CONSTRUCTOR only for test purposes?

Comment: Hmm ok maybe injection strategy Constructor should be set for my spring app and that's all...But I have section "uses" with additional mappers so I remember that with CONSTRUCTOR strategy I get NPE on these nested mappers...

Comment: @Filip I found your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451618/how-to-injectcustructor-a-spring-bean-into-abstract-mapper-of-mapstruct so please correct me if I'm wrong - with this approach I can test mappers without spring context but how to use this mapper in spring boot then? By injecting by constructor (or Autowired which is not recommended)?